# Should I use LassoCV or GridSearchCV to find an optimal alpha for Lasso?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

From my understanding, when using Lasso regression, you can use `GridSearchCV` or `LassoCV` in sklearn to find the optimal `alpha`, the regularization parameter. Which one is preferred over the other?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-cross-validation-estimator) the advantage of using a cross-validation estimator like `LassoCV` stands in the possibility of [warm-starting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-warm_start) results, which in turn leads to speed improvements. An exception is represented instead by `RidgeCV`.

Comment: @amiola Are you implying `LassoCV` is superior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the same results with both. `LassoCV` makes it easier by letting you pass an array of alpha-values to `alphas` as well as a cross validation parameter directly into the classifier.

To do the same thing with `GridSearchCV`, you would have to pass it a `Lasso` classifier a grid of alpha-values (i.e. `{'alpha':[.5, 1, 5]}`) and the `CV` parameter.

I would not recommend one over the other though. The only advantage I can see is that you can access `results_` as well as many other attributes if you use `GridSearchCV`. This may be helpful if you want a summary of all the models returned by the alphas you tried. On the other hand, as pointed out by @amiola, `LassoCV` can take advantage of using pre-computed results in previous steps of the cross-validation process (aka warm-starting), which may result in faster fitting times.

Comment: For either approach, can you get quick access to p values for parameters? Also, how do you determine what the grid of alpha values should be? That seems to be the whole point of cross validation is to determine what single alpha value to choose from, but I think even choosing the grid of alpha values appear to be science.

Comment: Sadly, `sklearn` does not return p-values. This is supposedly so because it's not a statistical package, but rather an ML framework. You can try `statsmodels` though, which is `sklearn` meets R. As to how to choose the limits of the grid, you can try a random search first, which should give you a good approximation, and then a grid search around the best `alpha` from the random search. Honestly though, `alpha=1` is usually good enough.

Comment: When you say "try a random search first," do you mean populate a grid from the random search, and then feed that into LassoCV? And then after LassoCV gives you an optimal alpha from the grid you provided, you then create another grid with values around this alpha and then feed it into LassoCV again?

Comment: Also, Re the p-values thing, that makes sense. I just started trying to pick up some data analysis stuff in Python in the past week, and one of my main questions I've had was why nothing in `sklearn` produces  p-values. It makes sense that it's designed more for ML/prediction rather than for inference/stats.

Comment: As a final comment, I suppose you can calculate your own p-values using `scipy.stats`, but that would be really tedious.